# django command does it require django server must be running?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have introduced a new django command which i can run from cronjob.  This is particulary helpful to get ORM specification.

To Run this django command, do we need the django server should be running ?

Comment: Thanks, but i did not get the point "if that command interact with server?" Could you kindly provide some more detail?

Comment: What i am doing is running the script python <path to manage.py> <commandName>

Comment: [Builtin django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/) does not interact with the server. Do you have your own custom command? If not, just run the command.

Comment: yes i have my own custom command introduced falsetru.

Comment: If that command does not interact with the server (`urllib.urlopen(...)`, `request.get(...)`, ...), it's okay to run the command without server running.

Answer (score 1):

No, the django server is a separate process completly independent from your custom command.

If you are using virtualenv (if you aren't yo probably should) keep in mind you must source the virtualenv or use the python interpreter within it in order to get the managemente command properly run.

Comment: Thanks, so it is just kind of standalone pyhton script, Only advantage to use such django-command is to get ORM  of the model. Kindly acknowledge if my understanding is right or wrong?

Comment: @Whoami : mostly: yes. You could get the same results from a true "stand-alone" script but you'd have more error-prone setup to do (sys.path, settings etc).